# Changing text navigation buttons in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, text

I'd like to change the default text navigation buttons for OSX (Mountain Lion).
That is, currently the key to move iterate tokens when editing a text file (or in XCode) is alt, and command for BOL/EOL.

I want to edit the default keys such that command is used to iterate through tokens, and either (alt+command+direction) or (fn+direction) is used for BOL/EOL.

I couldn't seem to find it in the key settings of each program, so I suppose it is some sort of default setting of the OS. Where and how can I change to achieve the above behaviour?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom key bindings that will apply in most OS X text editors (specifically, those that use the Cocoa framework).

Check out [KeyBindingsEditor](https://web.archive.org/web/20170911022145/http://www.cocoabits.com:80/KeyBindingsEditor/Manual/index.html), which provides a front end to the key bindings system.

Alternatively, you can create a `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` plist file in `~/Library/KeyBindings/` that allows you to specify custom keybinding actions. You should read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html) for the precise actions available.

In your case, you'll probably want the `moveWordForward:` and `moveWordBackward:` methods, if I'm parsing your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks! The KBE GUI did not seem to load, so I've edited the key bindings file myself. I am currently looking for more options rather than moveWordForward and moveWordBackward (Such as, when using both shift and cmd, only a work should be marked etc).

Comment: I am having some sort of weird issue. After editing the binding of cmd+right, Safari does not input cmd+right as it should've (Forward, Backward web pages). Why is that?

Comment: It may be that there's an active text field overriding the default behaviour. Make sure there are no active text fields, then try again.

Comment: There are absolutely no active text fields. Checked it also on sites that have no text fields at all. Any other possible explanation and/or solution?